# Function call inside lamda of thread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

```cpp
class Box {
    int _value;
public:
    Box(int value_):_value(value_) {}
    int getValue() const {return _value;}
};

void setBox(unsigned value, Box& box_) {
    box_ = value == 1 ? Box(1): Box(2);
}

int main()
{
    Box box1(0), box2(0);
    std::vector<std::thread> threadList;
    for(unsigned value : {1, 2}) {
        threadList.push_back(
            std::thread([&](){
                    setBox(
                        value,
                        (value == 1 ? std::ref(box1) : std::ref(box2)));
                }));

    }
    for(auto& thread:threadList) {
        thread.join();
    }
    std::cout << "Box1:" << box1.getValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Box2:" << box2.getValue() << std::endl;
}
```

**Output**

```
Box1:0
Box2:2
```

Why is the `Box1` value `0` not `1`. I know something is wrong with the code. Not sure what exactly is the issue. How exactly does lambda work here?

Comment: You are capturing `value` by reference into lambda, but its lifetime is valid only in the `for` loop. If the thread runs it's code after the loop has finished, you have a _dangling referenced. Capture by value instead.

Comment: @DanielLangr Please use the answer section for providing your solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has potential undefined behavior. The capture list `[&]` captures `value` as reference too. `value` is a local variable in the `for` loop, and will be destroyed when the iteration ends, after that the captured reference becomes dangled.

You can change it to capturing `value` by value.

```
for(unsigned value : {1, 2}) {
    threadList.push_back(
        std::thread([&,value](){
        //            ^^^^^^
                setBox(
                    value,
                    (value == 1 ? std::ref(box1) : std::ref(box2)));
            }));
}
```

Comment: Not to mention it has a modification that's unsequenced with respect to the threads

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I think it's fine because modifcation is performed on independent objects, isn't it?

Comment: Oh yes, you're absolutely right. So, in fact, the correct wording is that `value` will be destroyed when the loop _iteration_ ends.

Comment: Your modification seems to clarify it in the opposite direction. As you pointed out, there are two captured `unsigned value` objects here. So, the first is destroyed at the end of the first iteration, not when we get out of the loop.

Comment: Lovely jubbly :)